# Python classmethod not getting called

Tags: python

I am trying to test out a python ClassMethod like so:

```
class Test:
    a='inside method'
    @classmethod
    def testclass_method():
        print(a)
#Call the class method
Test.testclass_method
```

It prints:

```
<bound method Test.testclass_method of <class '__main__.Test'>>
```

How can I get it to print 'inside method'?

Comment: it isn't getting called because you *don't call it anywhere*. Calling a function requires parentheses, e.g. `foo(42)`. `foo` doesn't call anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `()` at the end of `Test.testclass_method`

It should be:

```
Test.testclass_method()
```

copy/paste from the comments for clarification:

The thing is that without the `()` you're not actually calling a method.
I highly advice you to read through [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) about classes in python3. Specifically the section about [method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) as it deals with exactly this issue...

Comment: While correct, questions like this that boil down to a simple typo should be closed and not answered.

Comment: True, if it was a typo. But this is not a typo. This is a concept question. I should have included what juanpa.arrivillaga commented directly on the question though.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused because in python 3, I can say print 'hi' and not required to say print('hi').  So the no parentheses syntax doesnt work here?

Comment: The thing is that without the `()` you're not actually calling a method. In python3 `print 'hi'` won't work. That's python2. I highly advice you to read through [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) about classes in python3. Specifically the section about [method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) as it deals with exactly this issue...

Comment: "in python 3, I can say print 'hi' " No, you cannot. that is specific to 2.x. `()` are required to call a function, no matter what function it is, in every version of Python. It just happens that in 2.x, `print` was *not a function*, and now it is. Parens for a function call are part of the language fundamentals and leaving them off is usually treated as a typo here, because every tutorial or intro reference material will explain this clearly in the same breath that it tells you what a function even *is*.